# Kubernetes : How to scale a deployment from another service/pod?

Tags: kubernetes, deployment

I have 2 services. Service A and Service B. They correspond to deployments dA and dB.

I set up my cluster and start both services/deployments. Service A is reachable from the external world. External World --> Service A <--> Service B.

How can I scale dB (change replicaCount and run kubectl apply OR kubectl scale) from within Service A that is responding to a user request.

For example, if a user that is being served by Service A wants some extra resource in my app, I would like to provide that by adding an extra pod to dB. How do I do this programatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every `Pod`, unless it opts out, has a `ServiceAccount` token injected into it, which enables it to interact with the kubernetes API according to the `Role` associated with the `ServiceAccount`

Thus, one can use any number of kubernetes libraries -- most of which are "in cluster" aware, meaning they don't need any further configuration to know about that injected `ServiceAccount` token and how to use it -- to issue scale events against any resource the `ServiceAccount`'s `Role` is authorized to use

You can make it as simple or as complex as you'd like, but the tl;dr is akin to:

```sh
curl --cacert /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/ca.crt \
    --header "Accept: application/json" \
    --header "Authorization: Bearer $(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/token)" \
    https://${KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST}:${KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT}/api/v1/namespaces
```

Comment: Thank you. You are right, I can use ServiceAccount to enable specific actions from a pod to the cluster. I haven't tried your solution yet. But I created a new ClusterRole with scale permission and attached it to the ServiceAccount for Service A. And installed kubectl in docker image for dA. This seems to work.